# Search Input System

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, search-box

I am working on a search project. I am new to html, css, etc., and haven't the slightest idea of how to accomplish this. Here is my idea in simplest form:

1. User visits website.
2. User finds search box (form) I created.
3. User types something into search box.
4. When the user clicks the search button, or presses enter, the website appends what the user typed into the search box and places it in this link and proceeds to follow the link:

https://www.example.com/results.aspx?q=***(USER SEARCH HERE)***

I have tried researching the topic but have not found anything useful on it. Everything is very unclear. If anyone can find a tutorial, or tell me what I might be doing wrong, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help that was given!

Comment: Do you mean by `https://www.example.com/` is your domain?

Comment: Well, I don't own the example.com domain, I am just saying that there would be some sort of domain there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the very default behaviour of a `form` with the `action` attribute applied:

```html
<form action="results.aspx">
  <input type="text" name="q">
  <button>Search</button>
</form>
```

Writing "Hello" in the input and pressing the search button or pressing enter, results in a URL like:

```
https://www.example.com/results.aspx?q=Hello
```

Giving the input another name, like `name="search"`, results in a URL like:

```
https://www.example.com/results.aspx?search=Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an `input` element and submit `button` and a `submit event listener` to call when submitting the form ( when clicking the button for search or click enter ), and on the `submit event listener` you can get the `value` of the `input` and add it as a query params.

For example.

```js
const search = document.getElementById("search");
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = `https://www.example.com/results.aspx?q=${encodeURIComponent(
        search.value
    )}`;
};
```

```html
<form onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
  <input id="search" type="text">
  <button>Search</button>
</form>
```